# Returning sum of values in linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, nodes

I have the following code:

```
int sum(LinkedList * list) {

  assert(list!=NULL);

  Node *currentNode = list->head;
  int sum = 0;

  for (currentNode = currentNode->next; currentNode !=NULL; currentNode = currentNode -> next) {
        sum = sum + currentNode->data;

        }
  return sum;

}
```

I want it to return the sum of all the values in the linked list *list. However, I keep getting a segmentation fault. Can anyone help me spot the fatal error?

Comment: Not sure about the error, but you're skipping the first element of the list, because you start the loop with `for (currentNode = currentNode->next;`. It should be `for (currentNode = list->head;`

Comment: You never check to see if `list->head` is NULL.

Comment: It would probably be more readable to skip setting `currentNode` until the for loop: `for(currentNode = list->head; currentNode != NULL; currentNode = currentNode->next)`

Comment: what does the debugger say is going on. At least which line fails

Comment: Thank you! I guess I had my panic goggles on and skipped over the details.

Answer (score 3):

Change your loop to:

```
for (currentNode = list->head; currentNode !=NULL; currentNode = currentNode -> next) {
    sum = sum + currentNode->data;
}
```

This will solve two problems:

1. It will check that `list->head` is not `NULL`;
2. It won't skip over the first element in the list when calculating the sum.