# Summing up the elements in a linked list recursively in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list

Suppose I have a Sum method to help sum the elements in a linked list recursively,

```
void Sum(Node *head)
{
    int sum = 0;   //I think this is the problem since it resets the sum on each recursive call
    while (head != NULL) {
        Sum(head->next); //iterate to the last node before null
        sum += head->data; 
        return;
    }

    cout << " The sum is : " << sum << endl;
}
```

The issue I'm having is I think due to my sum value being reinitialized to 0 with each recursive back call; what is a way to allow me to maintain the value of the sum once all the recursion is complete?

Comment: eh... Using C++ and not `<list>`?

Comment: There is no need for recursion here.
Possible duplicate here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28908852/returning-sum-of-values-in-linked-list

Comment: @Tatsuyuki Ishi, we have been writing our own linked lists with either node classes or node structs, so no haven't used #include <list>

Comment: Please make your container a `Container` (concept) in C++. That way you will be able to use the various std algorithms (like summing, sorting, and many more).

Comment: @StephanM.G. I'm interested in figuring out this problem recursively with the road block of the sum being reinitialized with each call though unfortunately. And thank you for that link it's more manageable for my skill sets, but still looking into a recursive solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be a lot simpler than what you have. Changes I suggest:

1. Change the return value of the function so it returns the sum.
2. Use the returned value in the recursive call.
3. Don't use a `while` loop AND a recursive call. Use one or the other.

Recursive version:

```
int Sum(Node *head)
{
    if ( head != NULL )
        return head->data + Sum(head->next);
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Looping version:

```
int Sum(Node *head)
{
   int sum = 0;
   while (head != NULL) {
     sum += head->data; 
     head = head->next;
   }
   return sum;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice regarding the while loop and recursive call, and thanks again for the feedback and helpful response.

Comment: You missed this line in your loop...`head = head->next;`

Comment: @ShaishavJogani, Keen eyes. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

**(C code)**

For the answer above me, doesn't the looping version need to be:

```
int Sum(struct node* head)
{
   int sum = 0;
   while (head != NULL) {
      sum += head->data;
      head = head->next; // This needs to be added to go through all nodes
   }
   return sum;
}
```

Also, I believe you can do this as well for a recursive method:
**(C code)**

```
int Sum(struct node* head) 
{

  if (head == NULL)
     return 0;

  return (head->data) + Sum(head->next);
}
```